Spring could not rollback when Exception is thrown
Here is a sample class code
@Transactional(rollbackFor = {Throwable.class, Exception.class})
public void notRollsBackCompletely throws Exception {
         service1.modifyDb();//Passes through
         service2.modifyDb();//Throws Exception
}

Now whatever changes done by service1 are rolled back, but service2 method still manages to commit the code (even though it has thrown exception after some updates/inserts). I really don't know how to proceed. I am using default transaction i.e. proxy based.
Note - No service method or inner method calls have @Transactional annotation

Can you add @Transactional annotation on your modifyDb() method and try again?

But modifyDb() is still getting committed. Any thoughts on why this should work.

I'd need to see more code to know why, can you paste the modifyDb() code please?

Ok give me some time i will do it by once is am out of office.
